# Typescript error ts(2352): How to get rid of 'unknown' type conversation on gRPC types generated from proto file

Tags: angular, typescript, grpc, grpc-web

Working on consuming a gRPC server stream call from Angular client. Getting below error type conversion error:

> "Conversion of type 'TestReply' to type 'AsObject' may be a mistake
> because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was
> intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. Type
> 'TestReply' is missing the following properties from type 'AsObject':
> prop1, prop2, prop3.ts(2352)"

To solve this, I need to convert the type as unknown before converting to the desired type like

```
data as unknown as TestReply.AsObject
```

How to fix the above without using unknown conversion. Here is the full code snippet:

**Service.ts**

```
  @Injectable()
    export class ApiMyTestService {    
        client: GrpcMyTestServiceClient;
        public readonly testData$: Observable<TestReply>;
  
    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
        this.client = new GrpcMyTestServiceClient(environment.apiProxyUri);
        this.testData$ = this.listCoreStream();
    }
  
   listCoreStream(): Observable <TestReply> {
    return new Observable(obs => {      
      const req = new SomeRequest(); //not significant to the type conversion problem
      req.setClientName("GrpcWebTestClient");
      const stream = this.client.getCoreUpdates(req); // Main gRPC Server stream Api call 
      stream.on('status', (status: Status) => {
        console.log('ApiService.getStream.status', status);
      });
      stream.on('data', (message: any) => {
        // gRPC Api call returns stream data here
        console.log('ApiService.getStream.data', message.toObject());
        obs.next(message.toObject() as TestReply);
      });
      stream.on('end', () => {
        console.log('ApiService.getStream.end');
        obs.complete();        
      });     
    });
  }
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {   
   public testReply?: TestReply;
   public coreData? : TestReplyWithData.AsObject[];
   private _subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private readonly _MyTestService: ApiMyTestService) {     
      this._subscription = new Subscription();
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {    
        this._subscription = this._MyTestService.testData$.subscribe((data) => {
           
           this.testReply = data;
            if (data) {
               var dtr = data as unknown as TestReply.AsObject // How to get rid of unknown here?          
               this.coreData = dtr.coreWithDataList;            
            }
        });
}
```

**Generated ts file from proto file showing the type definitions**

```
export namespace TestReply {
      export type AsObject = {
        coreWithDataList: Array<TestReplyWithData.AsObject>,
      }
    }
export namespace TestReplyWithData {
  export type AsObject = {
    prop1: number,
    prop2: number,
    prop3: number,
    //more attributes (of primitive types)...
    }
}
    // Classes  - TestReply and TestReplyWithData are not significant to the type conversion problem
    export class TestReply extends jspb.Message {
        // There are more methods generated but specifying couple of methods below for simplicity
        getCoreWithDataList(): Array<TestReplyWithData>;
        toObject(includeInstance?: boolean): TestReply.AsObject;
    }
    
    export class TestReplyWithData extends jspb.Message {
        // There are more methods generated but specifying couple of methods below for simplicity
        toObject(includeInstance?: boolean): TestReplyWithData.AsObject;
        static toObject(includeInstance: boolean, msg: TestReplyWithData): TestReplyWithData.AsObject;
      }
```

Comment: set type on your observable `public readonly testData$: Observable<TestReply.AsObject>;`, and you won't need to convert it later

Comment: Thank you @Andrei that worked :). Updated the return type to Observable <TestReply.AsObject> instead of Observable <TestReply> in the service method and the public testData$